# How to subtract days from a date using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Something surely extremely simple, but I've been browsing around for almost one hour and couldn't find:

Working with Python, I have a date `d="2020-01-22"` (means January, 22nd, 2020) and I want to calculate the date corresponding to `d - 57 days`. With datetime, surely, but how, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Use package datetime.

```py
# python3
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-01-22", '%Y-%m-%d')
print(d - datetime.timedelta(days=57)) # 2019-11-26 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code-

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.today()
new_d = d - timedelta(days=57)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.strptime`. this is the main function for parsing strings into datetimes. It can handle all type of formats, with the format determined by a format string you provide. You can read in detail [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time= datetime.strptime('2020-01-22", '%Y-%m-%d')
print(date_time)
```